# How to pull in notifications on app start?

Tags: android, notifications, push

In Android, for API 26+, when an application icon shows a red dot indicating that there are notifications pending for the application, the user will tap on the application icon expecting to see the content of the notification(s) within the application.

How can this be achieved? In iOS, you can pull in any pending notifications from the NotificationCenter when the application transitions to the foreground. Is there a similar way to do this with Android?

I know that the notification will be delivered to the application if the user taps on the notification itself but that is not the question that I am asking - just want to be clear...

Regards,
ac

Comment: @Kling Klang Why have you removed the word 'Android' from the title? This is a question specific to Android

Comment: That's what **tags** are meant to. Tags shouldn't be repeated in the post titles.

Comment: There are tens of thousands of posts with "Android" or "iOS" in the title. Do you plan to edit them as well? Next, time, if you edit a post, leave an explanation

Comment: No, I'm only interested in Android. And yes, I plan to fix them ALL. No need for an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep record (using shared preference **or** SQLite) of all incoming notification and all notification which are opened.

In this way you can have record of all unread notifications. On opening app you can show these notifications.

This will also have records for Dismissed notification also.

Comment: You have to keep record either by using shared preference or by SQLite else there is no solution to directly get all notification from notification bar

Comment: I see. That's unfortunate. What you are saying is that I would have to code up a notification listener that feeds notifications into some form of persistent storage (either shared preferences or SQLite)?